# Get request for exiting server

Tags: node.js, get, server

I am trying to connect to an exiting server using node.js however I receive  Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000 which I understand means that the server is already in use

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(3000,fucntion(){
console.log("listening on server 3000")}
```

How can i connect to an existing server then?

Comment: how are you connecting and where is your another server?

Comment: It's a local server listening on 3000

Comment: How are you trying to connect? did you do something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run another node server with same port.
Use request module to connect your server with another port to connect server that run on 3000 port.